# Android: correct way to simulate text input (not key input)

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I'm developing class based on `InputMethodService` for Android. My target is to support hardware keyboard with ability to remap some buttons and enter text using different charmaps.

I can override `onKeyDown` method so it will replace scan code of key:

```
public class Keyboard extends InputMethodService {
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        event = new KeyEvent(event.getDownTime(), event.getEventTime(),
                event.getAction(), SOME_NEW_KEY_CODE, event
                .getRepeatCount(), event.getMetaState(), event.getDeviceId(),
                SOME_NEW_SCAN_CODE, event.getFlags());
        ic.sendKeyEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
}
```

It works fine but I can't enter any Unicode characters. I can simulate text input using `commitText`:

```
public class Keyboard extends InputMethodService {
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        ic.commitText("some text", 1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But it works only for application with text fields. E.g. applications like Microsoft Remote Desktop are not receiving text input correctly. It's weird that it can receive English characters but not Cyrillic while on-screen keyboard can enter any Unicode character.

So, which way to simulate text input in Android is most correct?

Comment: You found how? I am also wondering how to do that.